# Which package can I find ConfigureHostBuilder in?

Tags: c#, .net

The following is part of a Class Library. I installed the following packages but it still cannot resolve `ConfigureHostBuilder`. Which package I can find it in?

```
<ItemGroup>
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="6.0.1" />
  <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="6.0.0" />
</ItemGroup>
```

```cs
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureLogging(this ConfigureHostBuilder builder)
    {
        const string outputTemplate =
            "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        builder.UseSerilog((_, cfg) =>
            cfg
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate));
    }
}
```

Comment: `ConfigureHostBuilder` is a method, not a class. You probably meant to use `IHostBuilder`

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`HostBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuilder?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) class, since `ConfigureHostBuilder` is (or was) simply a method naming convention

Comment: package: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions

using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ConfigureHostBuilder` is a method, not a class. You probably meant to use `IHostBuilder`.

[UseSerilog](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting/blob/main/src/Serilog.Extensions.Hosting/SerilogHostBuilderExtensions.cs#L56) is an extension method on `IHostBuilder`. It's part of the [Serilog.Extensions.Hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) package.

The package's landing page shows the method is used on an `IHostBuilder` instance:

```
public static IHost BuildHost(string[] args) =>
    new HostBuilder()
        .ConfigureServices(services => services.AddSingleton<IHostedService, PrintTimeService>())
        .UseSerilog() // <- Add this line
        .Build();
}
```

Your method should change to

```
public static class LoggingExtensions
{
    public static void ConfigureLogging(this IHostBuilder builder)
    {
        const string outputTemplate =
            "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss.fff} {Level:u3}] {Message:lj} {Properties:j}{NewLine}{Exception}";

        builder.UseSerilog((_, cfg) =>
            cfg
                .MinimumLevel.Information()
                .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Error)
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: outputTemplate));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! That's what I was looking for. Will accept the answer in a few minutes once it allows me to.

Comment: Is [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.configurehostbuilder?view=aspnetcore-7.0) the class ConfigureHostBuilder?

Comment: @shingo that's still the wrong class to use. No extension method uses it